# Redirect https://www.subdomain.domain.com is not redirecting to subdomain.website.com

Tags: htaccess, ssl

Hi i have a website example.com, i want to redirect my https://www.subdomain.example.com to subdomain.example.com

Its working when some one write url without https:// (e.g http://www.subdomain.example.com)

But not working when we tried to load website https://www.subdomain.example.com
Here is the error showing on page:

> This server could not prove that it is www.subdomain.example.com; its security certificate is from *.website.com. This may be caused by a misconfiguration or an attacker intercepting your connection.

Comment: Do you have a correct certificate for `www.subdomain.example.com`?

Comment: Yes https://subdomain.website.com is loading fine but getting error when i type www with url.

Comment: "Yes"?! ... you **do not** appear to have a certificate that covers  `www.subdomain.example.com` (ie. the www sub-subdomain) - that is what the error is telling you. You might have a cert that covers `subdomain.example.com`, but that is not the same host as `www.subdomain.example.com`.

Comment: @MrWhite thankyou for comment, then what you suggest ?

Comment: i can't even redirect this url to subdomain.website.com ?

Comment: The only way to resolve this and not get the _browser warning_ is to install a valid certificate on your server that covers the required hostname.

Comment: downvoted as the question is not specific to wordpres

Comment: @MarkKaplun but it's related to wordpress website.

Comment: lets see, maybe dictionary definition will help to explain what is the difference between related http://www.dictionary.com/browse/related and specific http://www.dictionary.com/browse/specific

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't appear to have a valid SSL cert installed on your server that covers the hostname `www.subdomain.example.com`, ie. the `www` sub-subdomain`.

The only way to resolve this and not get the *browser warning* is to install a valid certificate on your server that covers the required hostname.

Otherwise, unless the user accepts this invalid certificate in their browser (which they should not), then the request never actually reaches your server, so never sees the redirect.

Comment: pedantic: it does reach the server, it is just the initial SSL related negotiation fails.

Comment: @MarkKaplun Yes, by "server", I really mean the hosting account from which the files are served.

Comment: it still does reach it, otherwise changing the configuration on that level would not help ;). I think what is in play here is that HTTPS has two requests, one to set up encryption related parameters and the second one is the actual request. The browser do not like the respnse to the first one and therefor do not send the second.